# Network communication via Sockets. Is there a better way?

Tags: c#, networking, multiplayer

I'm building a game engine on the OpenTK framework that needs to support multiple players.

How I have the basic framework established is that there is a Client and a Server.  The Server binds and listens on a specified port, and the Clients connect to the Server's IP Address and Port to make a TCP socket.  The server then transmits a `World` object to all clients as they connect.

A `World` object contains all of the `Light` objects, `Surface` objects, `Mesh` objects and `Camera` objects.  With all of these objects, the `World` is responsible for rendering the game environment.

My idea is that each `Camera` object has a Unique ID, a position (X,Y,Z), and 2 angle values representing Zenith and Azimuth.  When any of these values changes (only the camera can move at this point.  Basics first!) I want to Serialize and send the updated `Camera` object to the Server, which then transmits this object to all of the Clients.  The Client then deserializes the new `Camera` object, uses its Unique ID and updates the existing `Camera` object in the `World`.  Since the Camera object consists of only 5 double values (X,Y,Z,Az,Ze) it shouldn't be a lot of data being sent over the network, but my implementation seems to slow down the Game Screen significantly

Is there a better model for Multiplayer network communication?  Is there any built in functionality in C# that handles this kind of communication?

Basically, I just need to update all of the other Clients when one Client's `Camera` changes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you by any chance using sockets synchronously? Because that's the main source of slowdown when using network, and no protocol changes will help you much in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sockets aren't the problem. That's just how TCP/IP networking works. Two things could be wrong. How you are using them and what you are sending?

Serializing a class and sending it and de-serializing seems huge for a game. Just send something like `CBIXYZCE` as in `CB` for camera begin, `I` for identifier, x coord, y coord, z coord, and `CE` for camera end.

When it comes to networking be as terse as possible.

In fact my example may be too big. The camera class should exist on the server and you only pass what changes. Oh and use UDP.

Comment: +1 for the two points I wanted to cover. First, use UDP, second, send the minimal amount of data as necessary! :)

Comment: In C# if using the Binary Formatter, the data actually sent should be quite small, that said, I agree, small data transfer is better.

Comment: UDP... Layer 3 really isn't my realm.  I'll give it a go!  And yes, I am sending a little bit more data than I was anticipating.  Like 800 bytes more...  Also, what about sending the map object?  it's 2-4 mb, but only needs to be sent across once.  How should I handle that?

Comment: @joe_coolish i'd read more about the tcp vs udp before deciding. I read articles and on forums, from my impression it's the other way around - unless you're developing an online FPS there is no reason to use UDP. I've seen claims about MMO's that moved their infrastructure from udp to tcp and were seeing improvements in performance a a result, sorry that i don't have anything to link though, just saying it as a motivator to read more not to use this or that

Comment: UDP by it's very nature is "unreliable" in that it provides no guarantees the data will arrive at the other end. Under ideal local network conditions it'll work just fine (probably), but on the internet you'll probably experience packet loss. As such, if you just send changes you'll start to have the wrong state at the other end of the network connection. You'll need to either send some sort of resync packet now and again to ensure everything is in sync, or some manual reliable connection stuff (which is what TCP is doing) to ensure no packet loss. You also can't guarantee packet order arrival

Comment: Well, since I'm sending the absolute positions and rotations of the objects, I don't have to worry about getting out of sync.  I changed my TCP over to UDP and also started sending and parsing a raw `byte[]` as opposed to object serialization.  This brought down message size from 800 bytes to 56 bytes.  It works pretty well.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @joe_coolish If both games have to have the same World data on their system then sending an ID of which World data to load might stop you from sending the entire object over. That would help with removing that from the first thing yo must send :) Also, fool around with UDP long enough and you will end up implementing a ReliableSend() when you want to guarantee critical packets make it (Like Start Match, End Game, Etc) and its not that hard to do (just keep sending until you received acknowledgement.. but don't require validation of the acknowledgement or you end up in infinite loop time :))

Answer (score 1):

You need consider the strengths and weaknesses of both TCP and UDP connection types. Generally UDP is used to send state data such as player position and actions. TCP is used to send information such as logins, level changes etc. Checkout this simple example of [how to create a client server application in minutes](http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/) using the open source network communication framework [networkcomms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I'm more in favor of using SSL to do the network communications in general. While it may seem unneeded, there have been hacks for some games to use the unencrypted transmission of the packets from the netcode to do some pretty nasty things. SSL would not prevent that completely, but it would add an additional layer of protection to slow it down.